# Can I connect IOTA with a website?

Tags: iota-network

Currently I am working on a project where I need to connect IOTA tangle. Can I do that? If yes, need guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

PHP: https://github.com/iota-community/iota.php

PHP Help: https://github.com/iota-community/iota.php/blob/main/help/000_index.md

Javascript: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js/

Javascript Browser Example: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js/blob/main/examples/browser/index.html

Comment: Just want to connect my website with IOTA and show a payment transaction for simulation purpose only. Can I do that? I am new in IOTA which is why I am having these confusions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a website you probably want wallet support. There is a wallet client written in rust but there are bindings.

### Wallet.rs

- Node.js

  - Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/tree/dev/bindings/nodejs
  - Documentation: https://wallet-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/nodejs/examples.html
- Python

  - Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/tree/dev/bindings/python
  - Documentation: https://wallet-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/python/examples.html
- Rust

  - Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs
  - Documentation: https://wallet-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/rust/examples.html
- Java: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/tree/dev/bindings/java

If what you want is to send data transactions, you probably will just want to implement the iota library. Again it is written in rust with bindings.

### IOTA Library

- Node.js

  - Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/nodejs
  - Documentation: https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/nodejs/examples.html
- Python

  - Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/python
  - Documentation: https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/python/examples.html
- Rust

  - Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs
  - Documentation: https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/rust/examples.html
- Java: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/java

But this just tells you were the code is. You might need to run a node, https://github.com/gohornet/hornet, which would involve finding peers, https://nodesharing.wisewolf.de/.

Comment: Yes I am working on a website and want to connect it with the tangle and just show a transaction for demo purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the bindings for that given your programming language preference.

[Github link](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings)